# Fiware-Orion: Subscribe to all entities

Tags: fiware-orion

In Orion 1.4.0 I used the following JSON to subscribe **for all entities**:

```
{
  "description": "Update average rating",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": ".*",
        "type": ""
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": []
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://URL:1026/v2"
    }
  },
  "expires": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 5
}
```

Today I tried this JSON with an Orion 1.7.0 and this doesn't work anymore. It returns the following error:

```
ERROR 400
{"error":"BadRequest","description":"entity type length: 0, min length supported: 1"}
```

I realized, that it's because of the `"type": ""`. I changed it to `"type": "*"`. The subscription works, now but I do not get any notifications. Probably the `*` is not the correct pattern to subscripbe for all entities.

For the reference: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2876

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `"typePattern": ".*"` instead of `"type": ""`.

Comment: I'll try. Is that backward compatible with older versions, e.g., 1.4.0?

Comment: Actually, using an empty type is disallowed in NGSIv2 API (see "Field syntax restrictions" section at http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable): "Minimum field length is 1 character". Thus, empty type in Orion 1.4.0 was a bug that has been solved in some moment between 1.4.0 and 1.7.0. Regarding typePattern, it seems it was introduced in 1.3.0  (see https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases/tag/1.3.0: "Add: Type pattern for subscriptions (#1853)"). Thus, is should be backward compatible in this case (although I haven't tested personally).