# FIWARE Orion: servicePath of a subscription

Tags: notifications, fiware-orion, broker

I'm trying to create a subscription to inform me on the change of some sensors values.

```
curl broker.waziup.io/v2/subscriptions -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Fiware-Service:watersense' --header 'Fiware-ServicePath:/#' -d @- <<EOF
{
  "description": "Send XXX when YYY",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "WS_UPPA_Sensor2",
        "type": "SensingDevice"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "SM1"
      ],
      "expression": {
        "q": "SM1>400"
      }
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "httpCustom": {
      "url": "https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/MAMDA5ZDJIMDM1NZVMZD/Message/",
      "headers": {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic XXX"
      },
      "method": "POST",
      "payload": "{ %22src%22: %2200393806412092%22, %22dst%22: %2200393806412093%22, %22text%22: %22WaterSense: Field is too dry. \${id} humidity value is \${SM1} %22}"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "SM1"
    ]
  },
  "expires": "2040-05-24T20:00:00.000Z",
  "throttling": 1
}
EOF
```

First question, what is the use of ServicePath in subscriptions?
It seems that it is used when retrieving the entities related to that subscription. So `/#` is valid. Is it correct (I don't find it in the docs)?

Secondly, say you want to create a subscription based on the values of several entities attributes. If those entities attributes have the same name (it's often the case), how do you reference them? Can you do something like:

```
"q": "Sensor1.SM1>100, Sensor2.SM1>100"
```

And something similar for the payload?

Comment: I have answered the first question. For the second question, I'd need a little clarification. You mean attributes with the *same* name in *different* entities? Is that correct? Thx!

Comment: I think he can use something like `idPattern` , like stated in this link: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230064/fiware-orion-subscribe-to-all-entities` . Or, maybe, just put all the interested entities in the `id` field in the subscription structure. @fgalan , what is the correct way to do this, specify many entities IDs in the subscription structure?

Comment: @fgalan yes attributes with the same name in different entities.

Comment: @Dalton I see how to put multiple entities in the `entities` field. But how to distinguish them in the `q` expression field, and in the payload field if they have the same attribute names?

Comment: I think in your `entities` field you will put all the entities of interest for you; in the `expression` field you will put your normal expression.

Comment: @Dalton I still don't understand. Say I have two temperature sensors S1 and S2. They both have an attribute Temp. How do I create an expression that triggers a notification if both temperatures are above 30 Deg?

Comment: Answer has been updated to address second question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding first question, using `Fiware-Service: /#` means that the subscription covers entities in any service path. In other words, any entity (no matter its service path within the service) would potentially trigger the subscription (as long as other conditions, such as entity id/type, attributes, filters, etc. match, of course).

Regarding second question, take into account that a given subscription is triggered by an update on a *single* entity. In other words, Orion recieves an update on a given entity and, if it match the conditions of the subscription, the subscription is triggered and a notification containing that entity is sent. Thus, the `q` filter refers always to the entity being updated (and in somecases notified, if the `q` filter and other conditions are met).

The role of the `subject.entities` field is to define the subset of entities to which the subscription refer. For instance, you could use `{ "idPattern": ".*", "type": "TempMeter" }` to refer to all entities of type `TempMeter`. However, if Orion gets an update for entity id `Meter1` of type `TempMeter` then the `q` filter refers only to that entity.

With regards to operations that "pack" several entity updates in one (e.g. `POST /v2/update`) they are decomposed in several single-entity updates, to which the above rules apply.

**Exception:** the initical notification sent at subscription creation time will include all the entities covered by `subject.entities`. However, this is a very special case (closer to the syncrhonous query operation than to the regular subscription behaviour) so it is not very meaningful. In this case the `q` filter adds to the set covered by `subjects.entities` in order to select which entities will be included in the initial notification.

Comment: OK I understand. The notifications are intended on a per-entity basis. To create notifications based on complex conditions involving several entities, it's probably better using CEP http://fiware-iot-stack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cep_api/
thanks!